# Laravel query builder return object instead of builder

Tags: php, laravel

Right now I've got this in my `Settings.php` model:

```
public function scopeFromCache($query)
{
    \Cache::rememberForever('settings', function () use ($query) {
        return $query->first();
    })->first();
}
```

Then in the `boot` method from my `AppServiceProvider` I do this:

```
$settings = Settings::fromCache()->first();
```

Is it possible to get the settings without the `->first()` like this:

```
$settings = Settings::fromCache();
```

So instead of returning a `query builder` return the object?

Comment: But isn't that what the `first()` method is doing, returning the first object from the Collection instead of the query builder? Why don't you wanna do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, **no**.

---

I would take another approach, since you are caching something forever (settings), I would make custom helper to get you these settings.

So create file **app/helpers.php**, in **composer.json** add

```
"files": [
    "app/helpers.php"
]
```

in "autoload" array.

Now forget about using scope, and create method (function) to use cache, just like you are doing now:

```
if ( ! function_exists('settings')) {
    function settings()
    {
        return Cache::rememberForever('settings', function () {
            return Settings::first();
        });
    }
}
```

Now anywhere in your project just call `settings()` and you get your object.

Comment: Much better thanks. Can I use ```settings()``` in my views aswel or do I have to add it in ```View::composer```?

Comment: You don't have to add it to composers, use it anywhere you like it is now global function, you can fire up tinker (`$ php artisan tinker`) and use it there as well.

Comment: Thanks really helpful!